# urllib request.urlretrieve error 400

Tags: urllib

I'm trying to download an image from a url

```
request.urlretrieve('https://website.com/image.jpg', "test.jpg")
```

The above works. However when I try to use:

```
a = 'https://website.com/image.jpg'
request.urlretrieve(a, "test.jpg")
```

It gives me error 400. How do I get the URL in there without causing an error?

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 188, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common reason for a 400 Bad Request error is because the URL was typed wrong. Try to `print(a)` to check if it indeed contains what you think.

the following lines work for me (python 3.5):

```
import urllib.request

# without variable
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", "test.png")

# with variable
google_pic_url = "https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(google_pic_url, "test2.png")
```

You can also try with another URL, like the one above to check if it's specific with your URL (this could be related to DNS issues, or server issues)